# Organize Database Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an android database with the following entries:
Name, Date, Location, StartTime, EndTime, Totaltime.

Here is my database code:

```
public class Database extends Activity {

// Used For Logging Database Version Changes//
private static final String TAG = "Database";

// Row Names//
public static final String KEY_ROW_ID_NUMBER = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
public static final String KEY_STARTTIME = "starttime";
public static final String KEY_ENDTIME = "endtime";
public static final String KEY_TOTALTIME = "totaltime";
public static final String KEY_TOTALTIME_ADDED = "totaltime_added";
public static final String KEY_DATE_EVENT_ADDED = "date_event_added";
public static final String KEY_SIGNATURE = "signature";

// Put All Rows Into A String//
public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROW_ID_NUMBER, KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_STARTTIME, KEY_ENDTIME, KEY_TOTALTIME, KEY_TOTALTIME_ADDED, KEY_DATE_EVENT_ADDED};
public static final String[] CSV_EXPORT = new String[] {KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_STARTTIME, KEY_ENDTIME, KEY_TOTALTIME, KEY_SIGNATURE};

// Column Numbers For Each Row Name:
public static final int COL_NAME = 1;
public static final int COL_DATE = 2;
public static final int COL_LOCATION = 3;
public static final int COL_STARTTIME = 4;
public static final int COL_ENDTIME = 5;
public static final int COL_TOTALTIME = 6;
public static final int COL_TOTALTIME_ADDED = 7;

// DataBase info:
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "community_service_Database";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "events";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; // The version number must be incremented each time a change to DB structure occurs.

//SQL Statement To Create Database//
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL
        = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE
        + " (" + KEY_ROW_ID_NUMBER + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_STARTTIME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_ENDTIME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_TOTALTIME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_TOTALTIME_ADDED + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_DATE_EVENT_ADDED + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_SIGNATURE + " TEXT NOT NULL"
        + ");";

// Define Variable DatabaseHelper db_helper//
public static DatabaseHelper db_helper;

// Define Variable SQLiteDatabase db//
public static SQLiteDatabase db;

// Integer TotalTimeAdded/
public static int TotalTimeAdded;

// Call Upon Database Helper//
public Database(Context ctx) {

    // Link DB_Helper To Database_Helper//
    db_helper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
}

// Open The Database Connection//
public Database open() {

    // Call DatabaseHelper To Open Database//
    db = db_helper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// Close The Database Connection//
public void close() {

    // Calls DatabaseHelper To Close Database//
    db_helper.close();
}

// Add A New Set Of Values To Be Inserted Into The Database//
public long insertRow (String name, String date, String location, String starttime, String endtime, String totaltime, String totaltime_added, String signature, String date_event_added) {

    // Gets All The New Values//
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

    // ALl New Values Being Added//
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    initialValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);
    initialValues.put(KEY_STARTTIME, starttime);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ENDTIME, endtime);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TOTALTIME, totaltime);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TOTALTIME_ADDED, totaltime_added);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SIGNATURE, signature);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_EVENT_ADDED, date_event_added);

    // Inserts The Value Data Into The Database//
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
public boolean updateRow(String rowId, String name, String date, String location, String starttime, String endtime, String totaltime, String totaltime_added, String signature, String date_event_added) {

    // Get Current Row By ID Number//
    String where = KEY_ROW_ID_NUMBER + "=" + rowId;

    // Gets New Values For Row//
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

    // Add New Values
    newValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    newValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    newValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    newValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);
    newValues.put(KEY_STARTTIME, starttime);
    newValues.put(KEY_ENDTIME, endtime);
    newValues.put(KEY_TOTALTIME, totaltime);
    newValues.put(KEY_TOTALTIME_ADDED, totaltime_added);
    newValues.put(KEY_SIGNATURE, signature);
    newValues.put(KEY_DATE_EVENT_ADDED, date_event_added);

    // Inserts The New Value Data Into The Database//
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}

// Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {

    // Get Specific Row ID//
    String where = KEY_ROW_ID_NUMBER + "=" + rowId;

    // Delete Row//
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}

// Delete Everything From Database//
public void deleteAll() {

    // Get All Rows//
    Cursor c = getAllRows();

    // Delete Row One By One//
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROW_ID_NUMBER);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));              
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}

// Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Get a specific row (by rowId)
public Cursor getRow(String rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROW_ID_NUMBER + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Get All Community Service Times//
public Cursor total_time_added() {

    // Set Total Time Added To Zero//
    TotalTimeAdded = 0;

    // Query Through All Rows//
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    assert c != null;
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {

        // Get Total Time Added//
        TotalTimeAdded  = TotalTimeAdded + c.getInt(COL_TOTALTIME_ADDED);
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    return c;
}

// Helps Make Database Work (Don't Touch)//
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);           
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

        // Destroy old database:
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        // Recreate new database:
        onCreate(_db);
    }
  }
}
```

Does anybody know a way to organize a database using the fields I have such as organizing it by name, date, or location? Thanks. What I mean by organize is I want the database to go in order by name for example instead of date in which a row was added to it.

Comment: what do you mean by organize?

Comment: Your Database is an activity? What's the significance?

Comment: Just a tip, don't bother using plain old sqlite, use some orm like ormlite, there's plenty of technologies that will make your life easier.

Comment: What I mean by organize is I want the database to go in order by name for example instead of date in which a row was added to it.

Comment: The extends activity was for a piece of code i'm no longer using. I meant to get rid of it but forgot. Its gone now.

Comment: you should not be worried about internal database ordering. you can sort it by whatever when you when you query it

Comment: Ok perfect thats what I mean how do I do that

Answer (score 0):

Storing rows in your database is an implementation detail. You shouldn't worry about how they are stored. Instead, you should worry about how to retrieve them in a specific order. To get all of the rows of your table you would use a query like this `SELECT * FROM my_table_name` this will list all the rows of your table. To order them in a specific order you just need to specify this at the end of your query like so `SELECT * FROM my_table_name ORDER BY name` (where name is the name of a column) you can reverse the order with the DESC keyword which stands for "Descending". `SELECT * FROM my_table_name ORDER BY name DESC`

You are asking about how to retrieve data in a specific way once it's stored. I suggest you check out w3schools tutorial on SQL. Here is the page on the ORDER BY keyword http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Edit: I also want to mention something else. Just from looking at the code there I can see you have a lot of comments in it. It's generally a good idea to limit the number of comments you have in your code. For example, you have this...

```
// Open The Database Connection//
public Database open() {
```

but see this comment here is redundant because your code is telling you that the Database is opening. Don't repeat yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how data are storing in the database because you can access your data in order that you want by using sortorder keyword in the cursor. Just like this.

```
String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
```

Here DISPLAY_NAME is the column name.

```
Cursor c = qb.query(newsDB/*table name*/, projection, 
                    selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
```